# How do we group/bin a measure in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, grouping, powerbi-desktop, ranking

I have written a a DAX measure that ranks over 5000 products based on their sales

```
Rank GMV = RANKX(ALLSELECTED(Fin[product_variant_id]),CALCULATE(SUM(Fin[gmv])),,DESC,Dense)
```

I need to group these ranks in bins of 0-1000,1000-2000 and so forth so I can identify the total sales coming out of these bins. However, I'm unable to find the group option for measure as I can for a normal column. How else can I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a measure for the bins, you need to create a calculated column, because you can't put a measure on an axis (rows or columns).

I did it like this (CC is for "calculated column"):

```
CC Sales = SUMX(RELATEDTABLE('FactInternetSales'),'FactInternetSales'[OrderQuantity] * [UnitPrice])
```

then using that, I created a Sales Rank calculated column:

```
CC Sales Rank = RANKX( FILTER(ALL('ProductMaster'),[Total Sales Measure]>0),[Total Sales Measure],,DESC,Dense)
```

Then finally, all I have to do is create the "bins":

```
CC Sales Rank Bin = FLOOR([CC Sales Rank],20)
```

(20 is the bin size interval {0,20,40,60...}).

Comment: But I need the ranks to be updated based on slicer selections. Would calculated columns work in this case?